# SWT how to have table that highlights entire row with single click, and edits cell with double click?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

SWT newbie here. So, what I want is to be able to highlight a whole row, along with being able to select multiple rows, and make it so that double click edits the cells. Is a focusCellManager necessary? Relevant pieces of code:

EditorActivationEvent

```
final ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = 
   new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(this)
   {
     @Override
     protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent
     (ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event)
       {
         return event.type == 
             ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL
             || event.eventType == 
         ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION
             || event.eventType == 
             ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED
             || event.eventType ==
             ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;
       }
  };
```

creation of TableViewerEditor

```
TableViewerEditor.create(this,
    mgr,
    actSupport,
    ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_HORIZONTAL|
    ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_MOVE_TO_ROW_NEIGHBOR|
    ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_VERTICAL|
    ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION);
```

code for mgr (focusCellManager):

```
focusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter drawHighlighter = new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(this);

final TableViewerFocusCellManager mgr = new TableViewerFocusCellManager(this, null);
```

The tableViewer (doesn't appear in the previous snippers as tableViewer is extended by another class and we use the other class, so I don't want to confuse you):

```
TableViewer vwr = new TableViewer(tableComposite,SWT.BORDER|SWT.FULL_SELECTION|SWT.MULTI);
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to use `EditingSupport` (TableViewerColumn.setEditingSupport) without the other classes.

Comment: I'm still a newbie at this, and I know you're legendary because I've seen like 15 of your posts on SWT. Can you give me some tip on how to use it and which classes I don't need?

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) article on vogella.com

Comment: Saw it, thanks! However, how would that prevent a single click from highlighting or editing a cell? One of my problems is that I have set double-click to edit the cell, which works, but single click still highlights the cell (no editing) instead of the whole row. This is even after having set the FULL_SELECTION bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `EditingSupport` on the table columns combined with the following TableViewerEditor seems to work for me:

```
TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(tableComp, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(viewer) {
  @Override
  protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(final ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {
    return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL
        || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION
        || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED
        || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;
  }
};

int feature = ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_MOVE_TO_ROW_NEIGHBOR | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_HORIZONTAL
    | ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION
    | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_CYCLE_IN_VIEWER;

TableViewerEditor.create(viewer, actSupport, feature);
```

Comment: Hi Greg. Thank you very much for that answer, it really helped! However, I have a new problem. Whenever I add a new row to the table, it is automatically highlighted, which isn't really much of a problem for me. The problem is that each new row I add remains highlighted and so I end up with a block of blue-highlighted rows. D you suspect what might be the issue?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments, ask a question.